# More economic ways to tune hyperparameters using Optuna

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, optuna

I am relatively new to machine learning. I am currently working on an imbalanced binary classification problem, and I need to test different models and how they perform with different types of sampling techniques. I have settled for a pipeline named `model`, composed by a preprocessor `ColumnTransformer`, a `TomeLink` sampler, and a `KNNClassiefier` estimator. When calling `model.get_params()`, I get the following output:

```
{'classification': KNeighborsClassifier(leaf_size=120),
 'classification__algorithm': 'auto',
 'classification__leaf_size': 120,
 'classification__metric': 'minkowski',
 'classification__metric_params': None,
 'classification__n_jobs': None,
 'classification__n_neighbors': 5,
 'classification__p': 2,
 'classification__weights': 'uniform',
 'memory': None,
 'preprocessor': ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                   transformers=[('knnimputer', KNNImputer(),
                                  ['policePrecinct']),
                                 ('onehotencoder-1', OneHotEncoder(),
                                  ['gender']),
                                 ('standardscaler', StandardScaler(),
                                  ['long', 'lat']),
                                 ('onehotencoder-2', OneHotEncoder(),
                                  ['neighborhood', 'problem'])]),
 'preprocessor__knnimputer': KNNImputer(),
 'preprocessor__knnimputer__add_indicator': False,
 'preprocessor__knnimputer__copy': True,
 'preprocessor__knnimputer__metric': 'nan_euclidean',
 'preprocessor__knnimputer__missing_values': nan,
 'preprocessor__knnimputer__n_neighbors': 5,
 'preprocessor__knnimputer__weights': 'uniform',
 'preprocessor__n_jobs': None,
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-1': OneHotEncoder(),
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-1__categories': 'auto',
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-1__drop': None,
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-1__dtype': numpy.float64,
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-1__handle_unknown': 'error',
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-1__sparse': True,
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-2': OneHotEncoder(),
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-2__categories': 'auto',
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-2__drop': None,
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-2__dtype': numpy.float64,
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-2__handle_unknown': 'error',
 'preprocessor__onehotencoder-2__sparse': True,
 'preprocessor__remainder': 'passthrough',
 'preprocessor__sparse_threshold': 0.3,
 'preprocessor__standardscaler': StandardScaler(),
 'preprocessor__standardscaler__copy': True,
 'preprocessor__standardscaler__with_mean': True,
 'preprocessor__standardscaler__with_std': True,
 'preprocessor__transformer_weights': None,
 'preprocessor__transformers': [('knnimputer',
   KNNImputer(),
   ['policePrecinct']),
  ('onehotencoder-1', OneHotEncoder(), ['gender']),
  ('standardscaler', StandardScaler(), ['long', 'lat']),
  ('onehotencoder-2', OneHotEncoder(), ['neighborhood', 'problem'])],
 'preprocessor__verbose': False,
 'preprocessor__verbose_feature_names_out': True,
 'random_under_sampler': TomekLinks(),
 'random_under_sampler__n_jobs': None,
 'random_under_sampler__sampling_strategy': 'auto',
 'steps': [('preprocessor', ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                     transformers=[('knnimputer', KNNImputer(),
                                    ['policePrecinct']),
                                   ('onehotencoder-1', OneHotEncoder(),
                                    ['gender']),
                                   ('standardscaler', StandardScaler(),
                                    ['long', 'lat']),
                                   ('onehotencoder-2', OneHotEncoder(),
                                    ['neighborhood', 'problem'])])),
  ('random_under_sampler', TomekLinks()),
  ('classification', KNeighborsClassifier(leaf_size=120))],
 'verbose': False}
```

Now, as you would imagine, I need to optimize the model's hyperparameters. However, both `GridSearch` and `RandomizedSearch` take forever to run, with almost always unsatisfying results.
For these reasons, I decided to settle for `Optuna`.

Examples and tutorials are very good but often use Optuna for deep learning. Also, the code-writing process seems intuitively wrong to me (writing grids is simple for short pipelines, but what about pipes such as the one I have?)

Thus:

Is there a way to obtains the grids to insert inside the `Optuna` `def objective(train`) function?
Examples are appreciated!

Comment: Optuna has a sampler called GridSampler. Also why would you want grid? The default optuna sampler is TPE, that is so much better than grid.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Optuna, and maybe the beginners tutorial use a grid to make it more clear? also, doesn't `GridSampler` only allows for numerical spaces?

If you don't  mind, could you add an answer where you show how to use it on the suggested pipeline?

Comment: The GridSampler can take non-numerical too. By the way can you update your post showing a minimal reproducible code with parameters. Only then I can create code on how it is done with optuna.